# Sort row of SQL table and display in HTML page

Tags: html, sql, sorting, triggers

I am having a Sql table created Name Main Table, from their I want to do sorting of Rows ,and place it in my html webpage, wat to do ?

```
      <ul id="gallery" class="nobullet">
              <li> <img src="2 Dove.jpg" alt="Runner Template" width="200" height="200"  class="img_border img_border_b" />
                <span>
                    <b>Dove</b><br />
                    *WANT TO ADD HERE.*
                </span>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the sql-data from the table in sorted order using the ORDER BY clause.

Then use your server-side language (you have not stated what this is) to construct, typically, an HTML table. Loop through the retrieved rows of data, inserting data from each row into an HTML table-row.

If you then want to be able to sort the table in the browser then this requires client-side, JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the table at database level using ORDER BY. At client side level, you can use  powerful JQuery Table Plugin - DataTable which gives you sorting option for each table column and you can also choose to sort a particular table column by default at the UI loading time using DataTable.